# how to kill unused connections

Tags: php, oracle10g, connection

i have web written in php (4.3.9) which is connected to the oracle DB (10g). user can submit query and see results. Time to time i got error in web application:

> ociplogon(): _oci_open_server: ORA-12516: TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack

users can not login and perform query. after reset of httpd, web goes to normal.

after googling i found:

- this error is caused because max limit of connections to the oracle is reached
- so i guess there are some dead/unused connections to the DB and are cleaned by reset of httpd
- user is connected by php command ociplogon which is persistent
- "OCILogoff() does nothing at the moment..." ([bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=11234](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=11234))

is there some way how to clean unused/dead connections? set some timeout?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of lot of open connection to the DB, after doing specified operation you are suppose to close.

Look into [`oci_close`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-close.php) to learn how to close an OCI connection and [`oci_connect`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) for more information about connecting to OCI.

Comment: oci_close is in php5 or higher. ocilogoff() is predecessor of oci_close. then i found this bug: "OCILogoff() does nothing at the moment..." (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=11234)